# What will be the unit testing for this code?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

What will be the unit testing code for the given code below...
Got stuck for a while so please help me find the solution...

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DemoAppCore
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static string CacluateGrade(float mark)
        {
            string grade = "";
            if (mark < 40)
                grade = "FAIL";
            else if (mark >= 40)
                grade = "PASS";
            return grade;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add code as text and as an image https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It can be whatever you want, unit tests don't have one single answer. You could do two calls, one with a number below 40 and one with a number above 40, and make sure you get the correct answer. But honestly I think it's overkill to have a method for this and it doesn't really need to be unit tested by its own.

Comment: Some test values to use would be 40, 40.0000001, 39.999999, float.MaxValue, float.MinValue.  And maybe a few more.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest you to simplify your code:

```cs
public static string CacluateGrade(float mark)
{
    if (mark < 40)
        return "FAIL";

    return "PASS";
}
```

Then, you can make tests for two conditions: `mark` less than 40, and `mark` greater than or equals to 40.

```cs
[Test]
public void CalcualteGrade_With39_ReturnsFAIL()
{
    var actual = Program.CalculateGrade(39);

    Assert.Equal("FAIL", actual);
}

[Test]
public void CalcualteGrade_With40_ReturnsPASS()
{
    var actual = Program.CalculateGrade(40);

    Assert.Equal("PASS", actual);
}
```

Comment: Or just `return mark < 40 ? "FAIL" : "PASS"`

Comment: Your test is incorret, 40 would result in a "PASS", you need test with a value less than 40.

Comment: @juharr, oh, sorry, of couse, you're right. I've fixed it.